# Frequency table categorical values

Tags: r, dataframe

I have the following dataset

```
set.seed(42)
cancer <- sample(c("yes", "no"), 200, replace=TRUE) 
agegroup <- sample(c("35-39", "40-44", "45-49"), 200, replace=TRUE)  
agefirstchild <- sample(c("Age < 30", "Age 30 or greater", "nullipareous"), 200, replace=TRUE) 
dat <- data.frame(cancer, agegroup, agefirstchild)
```

And just would like to have a simple frequency table telling me the size (n) of each subgroup. E.g size age 35-39 is 500 people, size 45-49 is 700 people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in base R you can use `table`:

```
table(dat$agegroup)
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `dplyr`:

```
dplyr::count(dat, agegroup) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = n, names_from = agegroup)
```

Comment: Thanks but what if I want to have all variables with frequencies in one table?